# How do I find all the lines that are in one file and not in another?

Tags: file, shell, unix, text

Say I got:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

and:

```
aaa
ccc
ddd
```

and I would like:

```
bbb
```

How would I get it?

Comment: I guess this has been asked many times. I cannot find an exact duplicate, though!

Comment: It looks like it should have been, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bash, Linux: Set difference between two text files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509533/bash-linux-set-difference-between-two-text-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep -vf`:

```
grep -vFxf file2 file1
bbb
```

Comment: looks like it should work but it's horribly slow on my actual fairly moderate (1MB) files.

Comment: You can add `-F` and `-x` options for fixed + exact matching, but I guess it will make it even slower.

Comment: grep -vFxf is very fast and does what I wanted. Gracies, el amic.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below command:

`comm` is used for Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line-by-line.

`-23` suppresses column 2 and 3.

```
$ comm -23 fil1.txt fil2.txt  
bbb
```